# url encode within a linq to entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have the below Linq to entities query

```
var spSiteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharePointURL"];
var spDocRoot = string.Format(Resources.Global.SharePointDocumentPathRoot, DateTime.Now.Year);


var Docs = (from s in _espEntities.SignupDocuments
            join r in _espEntities.RegistrationRequirements 
               on s.DocumentTypeId equals r.Id
            where s.TaxEntityPlatformId == thisTaxEntity.TaxEntityPlatformId
            select new NewBpnRegistrationRequestTypeSubmittedDocument()
            {

                 DocumentType = r.Description,

                 DocumentUrl = spSiteUrl + "/Documents/" + spDocRoot + "/" +
                   thisTaxEntity.TaxEntityPlatformId + "/" + "Registration/" +              
                   s.SharepointDocumentName

             }).ToArray();
  if (Docs.Count() != 0)
  {
      newBpn.SubmittedDocuments = Docs;

  }
```

What I want to do is to use the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method on the documenturl been passed.

Kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **LINQ to Entities** does not support this (because the method cannot be translated to SQL) while [**LINQ to Objects**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397919.aspx) does, you can try to load your data into [anonymous ojbects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397696.aspx) and then work with [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397919.aspx)

```
var Docs = (from s in _espEntities.SignupDocuments
            join r in _espEntities.RegistrationRequirements 
            on s.DocumentTypeId equals r.Id
            where s.TaxEntityPlatformId == thisTaxEntity.TaxEntityPlatformId
            select new 
            {
               DocumentType = r.Description,
               DocumentUrl = spSiteUrl 
                  + "/Documents/" 
                  + spDocRoot + "/" 
                  + thisTaxEntity.TaxEntityPlatformId 
                  + "/Registration/" 
                  + s.SharepointDocumentName
            })
            .ToArray() // Load data and continue with linq-to-object
            .Select ( n => new NewBpnRegistrationRequestTypeSubmittedDocument
               {
                 DocumentType  = n.DocumentType,
                 DocumentUrl   = HttpUtility.UrlEncode ( n.DocumentUrl )
               } )
            .ToArray ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this while calling the context, because there is no URL Encode function in SQL, so you will need to do something like the following:

Add the following properties to `NewBpnRegistrationRequestTypeSubmittedDocument`

```
TaxEntityPlatformId
SharepointDocumentName
```

Then:

```
select new NewBpnRegistrationRequestTypeSubmittedDocument()
        {

             DocumentType = r.Description,

             SharepointDocumentName= SharepointDocumentName,
             TaxEntityPlatformId = TaxEntityPlatformId

         }).ToArray();
```

Then iterate through the array, setting the `DocumentUrl` as follows

```
doc.DocumentUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(spSiteUrl + "/Documents/" + spDocRoot + "/" +
                   doc.TaxEntityPlatformId + "/" + "Registration/" +              
                   doc.SharepointDocumentName);
```

Comment: Thanks Maess for the answer also. The only challenge is adding an extra because this is a class exposed by a WCF service.

Answer (score -1):

```
        select new 
                    {

                         DocumentType = r.Description,

                         DocumentUrl = spSiteUrl + "/Documents/" + spDocRoot + "/" +
                           thisTaxEntity.TaxEntityPlatformId + "/" + "Registration/" +              
                           s.SharepointDocumentName

                     }).ToArray().Select(p=>new    
                 NewBpnRegistrationRequestTypeSubmittedDocument{
                  DocumentType =p.DocumentType,
                  DocumentUrl =HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.DocumentUrl)
                 });
```